# $addToSet not working with mongoDB in my API

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I know there are lots of topics about this, but I did not find any solutions for my problem, though.

To train my JS skills, I decided to create a quote generator, so I created the API and the frontend.

So, until now, everything worked perfectly, but my problems arrived when I decided to create a "category" system.

The principle is to create a category title and then each time a category is given to a quote, an array called "quoteId" is supposed to be updated in the database to store the quote ID.

Here is the model of the Category in mongoDB :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  quoteId: { type: Array, required: false },
  userId: { type: Array, required: false },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

And now, the code to update the quoteId array in the category collection :

```
exports.setCategoryProduct = (req, res) => {
  Category.updateOne(
    { title: req.params.categoryTitle },
    { $addToSet: { quoteId: req.body.quoteId } }
  )
    .then(() =>
      res.status(201).json({ message: 'Category updated !', status: 201 })
    )
    .catch((error) => res.status(500).json({ error: error, status: 500 }));
};
```

So, when I do the PUT request in POSTMAN, it returns the 'Category updated' message, but when I check in the collection, I can see that quoteId remains empty... I don't understand why it does not update whereas the request seems to be successful...

Thank you to all of you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly passing quoteId? Can it be something like "$" + req.body.quoteId, since it is a field?

Comment: Try logging both `req` and `req.body.quoteId` inside the setCategoryProduct function to see what is actually being saved.

Answer (score 0):

**You can replace this**

```
    { $addToSet: { quoteId: req.body.quoteId } }
```

**with  this**

```
    { $addToSet: { quoteId:{$each: req.body.quoteId } }}
```

as per mongodb documantation